# Oracle c# bulk copy of Datatable

Tags: c#, oracle

I want to insert bulk data into Oracle without using `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` because I want to use `system.data.oracleclient`

Comment: And what is your problem? What did you try? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Why do you want to use the ancient and [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/oracle-and-adonet?redirectedfrom=MSDN)  `System.Data.OracleClient` provider?

Comment: i have to use System.Data.OracleClient only cause in our system it is used every where and if try to introduce Oracle.DataAccess.Client then i'm getting lot's of error in application